# Difficulties with RegEx

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I wanna extract some latitude and longitude values from a KML file, which looks like :

```
      <coordinates>0.197118,48.003719,0.000000</coordinates>
      // ...
      <coordinates>
        0.197120,48.003719,0.000000
        0.197060,48.003792,0.000000
        0.198390,48.004059,0.000000
      </coordinates>
      // ...
      <coordinates>0.196763,48.003162,0.000000</coordinates>
```

So you can see in the text the format of coordinates is :

```
(space*)longitude,latitude,altitude\n    // or
(space*)<coordinates>longitude,latitude,altitude</coordinates>\n
```

So to catch latitudes, it's ok, I matched :

```
@".*?,(.*?),.*?$" // matching index 1
```

And for longitudes, I used the pattern :

```
@" * (<coordinates>)? (.*?),(.*?),(.*?)$" // matching index 2
```

I tried many things including this last pattern, but **I always get as matches** :

```
"<coordinates>0.197118",
"0.197120"
"0.197060"
"0.198390"
"<coordinates>0.196763"
```

And you got it : I don't want `<coordinates>`.

What's wrong in `@" * (<coordinates>)? (.*?),(.*?),(.*?)$"` ?

Thanks.

Comment: dont use regex for this. use a xml parser.

Comment: or a kml framework http://kmlframework.com

Comment: What if I want to use RegEx ? I think it's a way faster for me (in my case), I just think I'm missing something there.

Comment: Why should it be faster? Trust me: you are not the first to process XML with regex. And you won't be the last. But you also won't be the one who will do it nicely. XML/KML is made for parsing – not matching.

Comment: How can you parse without matching ?

Comment: In a well-formend format you don't need matching. Did u ever try XML parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so bad move by me here, just one more space standing :

Instead of :

```
@" * (<coordinates>)? (.*?),(.*?),(.*?)$"
```

I had to do :

```
@" * (<coordinates>)?(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)$"
```

That fix the problem ! No need of xml parser or something else for that…

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating it with all the greediness modifiers, look at [my sample here](http://regexr.com?34vk2) that just works:

```
(([0-9\.]+),([0-9\.]+),([0-9\.]+)[\w,]+)+
```

Also, I do agree that you shouldn't be parsing XML with regexps in general, but it can be an acceptable quick hack if it greatly shortens your code and you don't need anything else from the source file.

Comment: Yes I just need coordinates.

Comment: Well this should work and not require any kind of post-processing - you'll just get an array of triplets and separate arrays of lng/lat/alt values. I'm not sure which regexp engine iOS uses, but this is in PCRE syntax which ought to be universal.

Comment: I agree it's a good advice, but that's not what I want :/ I'm actually trying to fix with your link :)

Comment: It's the best way to extract all the data. If you need it in a slightly different format, just do some minor post-processing to reorganize.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use regexp, try a non-greedy:
@".*?". After matching you should iterate through the results and remove tags. The string left can be devided by @","